# how to sum string column in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table in my database that all of its columns is string.
The fields are name,date,price.
I put a label on a page and I want show the sum of column price in the label.
I try the below code but i have overflow error.

```
string reqcom = "select sum(cint(trim(price)) from mytable";                        
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(reqcom, reqcon);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
reqcon.Open();
OleDbDataReader dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();        

if(dtr.Read())
    this.totallbl.Text = dtr["price"].ToString();
```

Comment: You don't need `cint` & `trim` here. Ensure `price` column is a numeric field & do `SELECT SUM(price)` directly.

Comment: He said it are all string columns

Comment: Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: What is your SGBD?

Comment: I'm guessing this as an Access Database - what is the range of Integers in that system?

Comment: Cint returns a max value of 32767

Comment: cast it to bigint  `string reqcom = "select sum(cast((trim(price) as bigint)) from mytable";                   `

Comment: `cint` is not T-SQL, it is Access, as such, "cast" and "bigint" doesn't work.

Comment: ok he can use clng instead of cint

Comment: CLng(...) according to this https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Type-Conversion-Functions-8ebb0e94-2d43-4975-bb13-87ac8d1a2202

Comment: price column is string. I want convert it to integer then sum fields. my DB is access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the value at first, then get sum of them like code below:

```
select sum(cast(price as decimal(18,0))) from mytable
```

After that, use `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` instead of `cmd.ExecuteReader()`. ExecuteScalar will return just one value. Use the code below:

```
decimal totalprice = Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: Thanks Reza! how can i calculate sum of multi column separable?

Comment: If you want return more than one column, you must use ExecuteReader like what you did before. Then you seperate casted columns via comma like this: select sum(cast(price as decimal(18,0))) as totalprice,sum(cast(count as decimal(18,0))) as totalcount from mytable